# How to remove English language from ImpressPages

Tags: impresspages

I would like to completely delete English from my ImpressPages installation and leave there only Czech language. When I delete English using Languages menu, IP stops working with error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getUrlPath() on null in /.../Ip/Functions.php on line 595
```

Is there any way to do that? I'm customizing IP for a local customer and he is not interested in English option in any way.

Comment: On fresh installation, I have successfully removed English language. It still sounds like a bug of ImpressPages, but you have something specific that makes that bug appear. If you would pass me database backup, I could investigate. Of if it is a new website, do a fresh install.

Comment: Confirmed, that on a fresh install it works indeed. The problem surfaces, when I do this:
1. Fresh install
2. Create new language (CZ)
3. Move original pages (home and lorem ipsum) from english to CZ
4. Add "url" field ("en") to the english language in languages
5. Move CS up, to be the first language
6. Remove field "cs" in CS language
7. Remove english language.

I send you backup of database on your mail. It probably is a bug (or my fault), please feel free to answer this question with such simple reply, i will accept it as an answer in order to close this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in ImpressPages. The main reason is that ImpressPages doesn't change the language code field in page table when the page is moved from one language to another.